# laravel route with auth user if not loggin

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes

I have this code in my laravel blade :

```php
@if(Auth::check())
    <form 
        id="fileUploadForm" 
        method="POST" 
        action="{{route('scanningUpload',['user'=>Auth::user()->id,'person'=>$person->id])}}" 
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
    >
@else

<p> do some thing </p>
```

but now I got this error:

```
Attempt to read property "id" on null for Auth::user()->id
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: try ‘@auth’ instead of if

Comment: @Maksim i dont understand where use it?

Comment: You're certain this particular bit of code causes the error? It shouldn't.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, and it confused me

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this
@auth
    // The user is authenticated...
@endauth
 
@guest
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```

For more please visit [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#authentication-directives)

Comment: This is just shorthand for essentially the same thing OP's trying.

Comment: Have you tried this? Isn't it still working?